# How to show error message to user in MVC calling Web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on a MVC Web App which is calling a Web API. In my Create (`POST`) method, a user will enter email addresses of some users in the database. I have a check to enter the email only if the email does not already exist in the database or not. If it already exists, I want to be able to show an error message to the user "*Email already exists*".

I thought `HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Email exists already."` would work, but I think it will only show in PostMan. How can I show it on the MVC side with like `ViewBag.ErrorMessage`?

**API**

```
public IHttpActionResult PostApprovedUsers(ApprovedUsers approvedUsers)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

if (!db.ApprovedUsers.Any(u => u.Email == approvedUsers.Email))
{
    db.ApprovedUsers.Add(approvedUsers);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
else
{
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Email exists already.");
}
return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = approvedUsers.Email }, approvedUsers);
```

**MVC Create**

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Email,FirstName,LastName")] ApprovedUsers approvedUsers)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        token = Session.GetDataFromSession<string>("access_token");
            client.Headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            client.UploadValues(apiUrl, "POST", new NameValueCollection()
            {                      
                { "Email", approvedUsers.Email },
                { "FirstName",approvedUsers.FirstName },
                { "LastName",approvedUsers.LastName }
            });                
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: You are not handling the response of API in Create action method.  You need to check the status code coming in the response and set in the viewbag before returning the view.

Comment: @Luke - He is making the call in his Create Controller using Webclient.  OP: Is there a reason you have segregated your logic this way? If you are writing both the api and the controller, there is not reason to have one controller call the other one. You should just use a common service here and call that from the create controller.

Comment: @AndrewHunter I took over this project which someone else created in my internship. Somehow I am supposed to finish it by next week and it is a mess. Especially I am new to ASP.Net.

Comment: Is this a project that has a public repo or are you allowed to make it public? There seems to be some interesting design decisions made here.

Comment: No, no repositories were created. I am sorry, I don't know what you mean by "Public" repo? My manager just told me to fix the errors and complete the remaining features for this API and then work on the UI of the MVC side.

Comment: Well webclient isn't really the way to go here. If you must, what you need to do is take the return value from webclient, and then pass that value back into your view. However having the API return NotFound for an already existing account doesn't seem right either. Give me a little bit and I will setup an example app on a public git repo you can look at.

Comment: @AndrewHunter Please, any kind of info or source for reference would help out a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Is this all one big MVC project?

Comment: Yes, it is. And later on they intend to use the API for the mobile app

Comment: Ok, that explains some of this. What needs to happen them is that common functionality of user checking needs to be factored out into a service and then injected into both the API controller and the view controller. I will put that together in the example and post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with what you were seeing is that you were not in fact doing anything with the return value of webclient. That is ok though, since based on our discussion everything is in the same project and that would not be how you would want to do this using ASP.NET MVC and Web API.

Since these are all in the same project, we do want to combine common functionality but not within a controller. The DB service should be abstracted away into a seperate project - or class - and then injected into both controllers using some form of [IoC Container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921087.aspx). There are a couple of options available and I personally usually use [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) for my .NET projects.

Assuming you have that functionality your MVC Controller and API controller should then both program against that abstraction. [Interface based programming](http://www.codemag.com/article/0205091) is how .NET works best.

With that in mind your new API controller would look something like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostApprovedUsers([Bind(Include="Email, FirstName, LastName")]ApprovedUser approvedUser)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        if (_db.UserExists(approvedUser))
        {
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Email exists Already");
        }

        _db.AddUser(approvedUser);
        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new {id = approvedUser.Email}, approvedUser);
    }
```

Where _db is the service that gets injected into the controller. Please not how common functionality such as checking to see if a user exists and adding a user are wrapped behind the abstraction:

```
public interface IMyFakeDbService
{
    IQueryable<ApprovedUser> ApprovedUsers { get; }

    int RemoveUser(ApprovedUser user);

    int RemoveUser(string email);

    bool UserExists(ApprovedUser user);

    void AddUser(ApprovedUser user);
}
```

This then brings us to your MVC Controller. The same principle applies; since all the common functionality is in the db service just inject that into the controller instead of calling the API controller. You will see that you can use [ModelState.AddModelError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.addmodelerror(v=vs.118).aspx) here to pass information back into the view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Email, FirstName, LastName")]ApprovedUser user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (!_db.UserExists(user))
            {
                _db.AddUser(user);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("","A user with that email already exists");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**Finally**

1. I made a public git repo with a complete project [here](https://github.com/AndrewPHunter/MvCAPI/tree/master)
2. The DB calls should be [async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async). You are wasting server resources if not
3. If you want to learn MVC real quick I would suggest [Pro ASP.NET MVC 5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430265299) and [Pro ASP.NET Web API2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484200861)

Comment: Thank you so very much for all the help. Really appreciate it. Just wanted to ask how can I add the token code?

Comment: So you were adding the token code because the API was sitting behind some form of authorized only attribute. You would handle security for the MVC controller in that controller. The sample code you posted did not have that controller being restricted, is it suppose to be?

Comment: It looks like you already have the session security cookie set in the controller since you access it from session state 'Session.GetDataFromSession<string>("access_token");'. That means the MVC controller should already be protected and you can just call the service directly.

Comment: The controller is not really restricted, but I have to access the token for every user or something.

Comment: Well I would look at the requirements for that. For the use case you posted, it is not required. If the answer works for you would you mind marking the answer as accepted? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I always use [`Ok<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.ok(v=vs.118).aspx), where T is a model I defined which have 3 variables, one will identify the status (true, false) and one will be a string message, and one will have data type of `List<object>` which I need to receive at end point, then you can modify the error message as you want
in your case instead of this

`return BadRequest(ModelState);`

I will replace it with something like this

`return Ok<MyResponse>(new MyResponse{ Message = "Error Message Here", Status = false});`

then once you get your content you can desirialize it into your object

```
MyResponse response = new MyResponse();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
// ok will return success status code, but you will depend on your status to know if it was success or error happened 
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // Desirialize your result 
    response = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyResponse>();
}
// then get the message, 
if(response.Status)
{
 //it was fine, return something ..
 }
else {
// Error happened, get your error message and disaply it, if you want as viewbag
ViewBag.ErrorMessage = response.Message;
// do something
}
```

Comment: @Muzner Do you have an example I can follow for reference please? I am trying to understand your example code, but I am not being able to understand fully. Where would you call `return Ok<MyResponse>(new MyResponse{ Message = "Error Message Here", Status = false});` ? Do I return that instead of `return RedirectToAction("Index");` ?

Comment: This is your api return, not your mvc controller, api return this when there is an error, example email not found, or model is not valid, so instead of BadRequest return the one i used, this way you can modify error message as you want.